# Lag time issue with blackberry torch 9800

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

We have developed an application using blackberry api 4.2.1. The application works fine in blackberry devices running with OS 5.0. But for devices like blackberry torch with OS 6.0 there is a lag time issue when filling out a form. If i want to enter a text in basic edit field its takes around 40 seconds to diaply the typed text in the field. This is the case for other controls like date field, object choice field, check box and radio button field.

I have no idea why this problem occurs in device with OS 6.0 especially in blackberry torch 9800.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthick K.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with OS6 api ?

Comment: The JAD for blackberry6 device is prepared using OS6 API only. The form we have in BB is a big one. The form has 100 questions most of them are ObjectChoiceField and BasicEditField. Each and every field is registered with a listener. BasicEditField is more slower than ObjectChoiceField. We don't have this problem in devices with OS4.5 and OS5.0.

The problem is in devices with OS 6.0 especially blackberry torch 9800

Answer (score 0):

The JAD for blackberry6 device is prepared using OS6 API only. The form we have in BB is a big one. The form has 100 questions most of them are ObjectChoiceField and BasicEditField. Each and every field is registered with a listener. BasicEditField is more slower than ObjectChoiceField. We don't have this problem in devices with OS4.5 and OS5.0.

The problem is in devices with OS 6.0 especially blackberry torch 9800.

Comment: Please delete this answer and add it to your question, you can edit it. Or only leave the comment.